# login с помощью API. session yii2

Tags: php, yii2, api, сессия

Отправляю пост запрос на другой сайт, туда где находится форма. Идентификацыя проходит нормально, создаётся сессия. Но когда захожу в этот сайт то сессии нету и мне надо сново авторизаватся на сайте чтоб зайти в свой аккаунт.
Почему удаляется сессия после API запроса? Что я упустил?

Answer (score 1):

Сессия действительна на время работы клиента. То есть в браузере сессия будет жить пока не закроете последнюю вкладку сайта. В случае API она закроется сразу же после завершения запроса. Чтоб повторно открыть эту же сессию(если это предусмотренно) используют ответ от сервера, который содержит в себе Cookie авторизации. Которые повторно отправляются на сервер при следующем запросе в заголовках. Вообще-то то что вы делаете как-то попахивает неправильной архитектурой. Но если вам нужно продолжить. То можете анализировать ответ от API, вытягивать оттуда SessionID и отправлять его при повторном заходе на сайт

Если API дергаете через CURL, то можно так указать путь для сохранения и подтягивания кук

```
$cookie = __DIR__.'/../cookie/mysite.cookie'

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

Обратите внимание на:

**ResponseHeaders['set-cookie']** - для первого запроса
[image: **ResponseHeaders['set-cookie']** - для первого запроса]
**RequestHeaders['cookie']** - для второго запроса
[image: **RequestHeaders['cookie']** - для второго запроса]

Comment: Cookie авторизации, как найти их?

Comment: Они передаются в Response Header

Comment: а $cookie, что должно быть, я за ранее должен знать какие кукки  отпровлять?

Comment: [http://www.phpcubes.com/what-is-the-difference-between-session-and-cookies.html](http://www.phpcubes.com/what-is-the-difference-between-session-and-cookies.html)

Comment: Я отпровляю куки 'my_name'. В echo $result я вижу уже залогинивший, но в айфреме - нет.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "my_id=321;my_name=....w@mail.ru;my_fullName=test;my_authid=132");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "my_id=321&my_name=....w@mail.ru&my_fullName=test&my_authid =132");

Comment: Ну вы бы упомянули раньше что работаете с iframe. Это еще отдельная история
https://geektimes.ru/post/112077/

Comment: можете помочь с этим?

Comment: Как уже говорил раньше. Это попахивает неправильной архитектурой. Вообще таких проблем возникать не должно. Опишите полностью, что вы делаете, зачем вы это делаете, и почему именно вам нужно делать это именно так. Что за API, что за сайт и т.д.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43308/discussion-between-ninazu-and-taron).